# vuejs site slow downs / input fields gets freezed when i fill the same form 3-4 times

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, vite, inertiajs

my problem is when i fill the form for first 2-3 times, everything goes well, but after 3-4 times, the sites gets slow down, the input fields gets freezed, i am new in vuejs, so don't know what could be the problem in it. Any small help will be much appreciated.

```
form.vue // below code is a small part of the form

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <ad-vechicle-input optional label="weight in kg"
    v-model="formData.vehicle_body_construction.weight"
    :modelValue="this.formData.vehicle_body_construction.weight" valueType="Number"/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div>
        <div :class="['py-1 text-xs md:text-sm',showError && !formData.vehicle_body_construction.color_id ? 'custom-red-text': '']">
            Main color
        </div>
        <v-select
            :class="['input-select ',showError && !formData.vehicle_body_construction.color_id ? 'custom-red-border rounded-md placeholder-red' : 'placeholder-text']"
            :options="colors"
            v-model="formData.vehicle_body_construction.color_id"
            placeholder="Select"
        />
    </div>
    <div v-if="showError && !formData.vehicle_body_construction.color_id" class="custom-red-text mt-2">Must be filled in</div>
</div>

//code for mounted and autosave:
async mounted(){
    await Promise.all([
        this.getModelAndMake(),
        this.getFuel(),
        this.getGearbox(),
        this.getWheelDrive(),
        this.getColor(),
        this.getBodyType(),
        this.getCondition(),
        this.getMake()
    ]);

    this.startInterval()

    const currentUrl = window.location.href;
    const keyword = 'code';
    if (currentUrl.includes(keyword)) {
        this.updateData();
    }
},

startInterval() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.isAnyFieldFilled) {
            this.AutoSave();
        }
    }, 30000);
},

async AutoSave() {

    if(this.imagesLink && this.imagesLink.length>0 && this.selectedImage){
        const selectArr=this.imagesLink.filter((item)=> this.imagesLink[this.selectedImage]!=item)
        this.imagesLink=[this.imagesLink[this.selectedImage],...selectArr]
        this.tempSelectedImage = this.selectedImage
        this.selectedImage=null
    }

    var fd = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.formData));

    fd.make_id = fd.make_id ? fd.make_id.value : null;
    fd.model_id = null;
    fd.vehicle_body_construction.body_type_id = fd.vehicle_body_construction.body_type_id ? fd.vehicle_body_construction.body_type_id.value : null;
    fd.vehicle_body_construction.color_id = fd.vehicle_body_construction.color_id ? fd.vehicle_body_construction.color_id.value : null;
    fd.vehicle_body_construction.tax_class_id = null;
    fd.vehicle_condition_mileage.condition_id = fd.vehicle_condition_mileage.condition_id ? fd.vehicle_condition_mileage.condition_id.value : null;
    fd.vehicle_condition_mileage.exemption_registration_fee = fd.vehicle_condition_mileage.exemption_registration_fee == "accepted" ? 1 : 0;
    fd.vehicle_condition_mileage.total_price_specification = fd.vehicle_condition_mileage.total_price_specification == "accepted" ? 1 : 0;
    fd.vehicle_condition_mileage.total_price = this.totalPrice ? this.totalPrice : this.formatPrice
    fd.vehicle_contact_information.country_id = fd.vehicle_contact_information.country_id ? fd.vehicle_contact_information.country_id.value : null;
    fd.vehicle_engine_drive.fuel_id = fd.vehicle_engine_drive.fuel_id ? fd.vehicle_engine_drive.fuel_id.value : null;
    fd.vehicle_engine_drive.gear_box_id = fd.vehicle_engine_drive.gear_box_id ? fd.vehicle_engine_drive.gear_box_id.value : null;
    fd.vehicle_engine_drive.wheel_drive_id = fd.vehicle_engine_drive.wheel_drive_id ? fd.vehicle_engine_drive.wheel_drive_id.value : null;
    fd.annonsor = (fd.annonsor == 3) ? 'private' : (fd.annonsor == 4) ? 'dealer' : (fd.annonsor == 5) ? 'selger' : fd.annonsor;
    this.imagesLink = this.imagesLink.map(image => image.replace('/laravel_public/storage/', ''));
    fd.images = this.imagesLink

    if(this.textArea && fd.vehicle_body_construction.equipment_type== 'copypaste' && this.formData.vehicle_body_construction.equipment_list.length != 0){
        fd.vehicle_body_construction.equipment = fd.vehicle_body_construction.equipment_list.trim().split("\n")
    }

    delete fd.vehicle_body_construction.equipment_list

    try {
        var apiurl = `/api/update-vehicle/${this.user.id}`;
        if(this.oldVehicleId){
            apiurl += `/${this.oldVehicleId}`;
        }
        const res = await axios.post(apiurl, fd);
        if (res.data.status) {
            this.oldVehicleId = res.data.vehicle.id;
            this.bCode = res.data.vehicle.code;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.response.data.message);
    }

    this.AdSavedAlert = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.AdSavedAlert = false;
    }, 3000);
},
```

AdVehicleInput.vue // code for custom input component.

```
<template>
    <div v-if="multipleselect">
        <div :class="['py-1 text-xs md:text-sm',labelClass]">
            <slot name="checkboxinput"></slot>
            {{ label }} <span v-if="optional" class="text-gray-500">(optional)</span>
            <slot name="labeloptional"></slot>
        </div>
        <v-select
            :class="['input-select',inputClass]"
            :options="options"
            @option:selected="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)"
            @input="onMakeChange"
            v-model="modelValue"
        />
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <div class="text-xs md:text-sm py-2">
            <div :class="['py-1 whitespace-nowrap', labelClass]">
                <slot name="checkboxinput"></slot>
                {{ label }} <span v-if="optional" class="text-gray-500">(optional)</span>
                <slot name="labeloptional"></slot>
            </div>
            <div
                v-if="prefixLabel"
                class="flex items-center text-[16px] rounded-md border-[1px] border-slate-300 px-2"
            >
                <label for="">+47</label>
                <input
                    v-model="inputValue"
                    type="text"
                    :placeholder="placeholder"
                    class="w-full !border-none !focus:border-none py-2.5 px-[7px] shadow-none"
                    @input="formatInput"
                />
            </div>
            <div v-else :class="['flex items-center rounded-md border-[1px] border-slate-300 px-2',inputClass]">
                <input
                    v-model="inputValue"
                    type="text"
                    :placeholder="placeholder"
                    class="w-full !border-none !focus:border-none p-2.5 shadow-none"
                    @input="ValidateInput"
                    :disabled="disabled"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        label: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        prefixLabel: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        optional: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        multipleselect: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        options: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [],
        },
        modelValue: {
            default: '',
        },
        placeholder: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        valueType: {
            type: String,
            default: 'text',
        },
        customClass: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => ({}),
        },
        disabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        }
    },
    emits: ['update:modelValue'],
    data() {
        return {
            inputValue: this.modelValue,
        }
    },
    watch: {
        modelValue: {
            handler(newValue) {
                this.inputValue = newValue;
            },
            immediate: true,
        },
        inputValue(newValue) {
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', newValue);
        },
    },
    methods: {
        emitEvent(option) {
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.inputValue)
        },
        formatInput() {
            // Remove any non-numeric characters
            this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')

            // Limit the length to maxLength digits
            if (this.inputValue.length > 8) {
                this.inputValue = this.inputValue.substring(0, 8)
            }

            // Emit the value upwards to the parent component
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.inputValue)
        },
        onMakeChange(newValue) {
            this.$emit("update:modelValue", newValue);
        },
        ValidateInput(){
            if(this.valueType == "Number"){
                this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            }else if(this.valueType == "SP"){
                this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/^0+/, '').replace(/\D/g, '');
            }else if(this.valueType == "decimal"){
                this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
                const parts = this.inputValue.split('.');
                if (parts.length > 2) {
                    this.inputValue = parts[0] + '.' + parts.slice(1).join('');
                }
            }else if(this.valueType=="ZipCode"){
                this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                if (this.inputValue.length > 4) {
                    this.inputValue = this.inputValue.substring(0, 4);
                }
            } else if (this.valueType === "disabled") {
                this.inputValue = 0;
                this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.inputValue);
            } else if(this.valueType == "model_spec"){
                if (this.inputValue.length > 60) {
                    this.inputValue = this.inputValue.substring(0, 60);
                }
            }else if(this.valueType=="cylinder_volume"){
                this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '');
            }

            if(this.inputValue == ""){
                this.inputValue=null;
            }
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.inputValue);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        labelClass() {
            return this.customClass.custom_red_text ? 'custom-red-text' : '';
        },
        inputClass() {
            return this.customClass.custom_red_border ? 'custom-red-border' : '';
        },
        inputType() {
            return this.valueType === 'number' ? 'text' : 'text';
        },
    },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.input-select {
    .vs__dropdown-toggle {
        padding: 0.6rem;
        border-radius: 0.3em;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .vs__search {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0 !important;
        background: transparent !important;
        border: none !important;

        &:focus {
            outline: none !important;
            box-shadow: none !important;
        }
    }
    .vs__search,
    .vs__selected {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

.custom-red-border .vs__dropdown-toggle{
    border:none !important;
}

</style>
```

just to give you more idea about my code, let me tell you 1 thing in my mounted cycle, i am calling around 8 api's, and secondly when someone starts filling my form, an autosave function triggers after every 30 seconds and calls the save api to for automatic submission of data.

Please tell what could be the possible reason for freezing of input fields and what should i do now ?

Comment: Looks to me like your problem is not with Vuetify but with your 'mounted cycle' (?) in Vue, or with the autosave function - neither of which you show here. Also, although it won't help your problem, look at Vuetify rules (at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/) for a better way of validating inputs.

Comment: @quilkin thanks for responding, i have added  the mounted and autosave function code, please have a look.

Comment: Hmmm - there's a lot of code there. Ideally you should try to create a smaller example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, I see you are using `setInterval()` -are you also using `clearInterval()` when the component is unmounted? If not you may have several intervals running concurrently.